# Abstract Algebra (splitting fields)

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Suppose $f(x)∈F[x]$ is a polynomial of degree $n$. Let $k$ be its splitting field. Prove that $[K:F]\leq n!$.

I figure I am supposed to use induction on n, but I am not sure how to go about doing that. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you learned about Galois groups?

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

Assume $\;f(x)\in\Bbb F[x]\;$ is irreducible, $\;\deg f=n\;$:

$$\text{Our polynomial's a root in the field}\;\;\Bbb F_1:=\Bbb F[x]/\langle f(x)\rangle\;,\;\;\text{namely}\;\;\alpha:=\overline x:=x+\langle f(x)\rangle$$

We can write $\;f(x)=(x-\alpha)q_1(x)\in\Bbb F_1[x]\;\text{ and}\;\;\deg q_1=n-1$

Note that $\;[\Bbb F_1:\Bbb F]=n\;$ . Assume $\;q_1(x)\;$ is irreducible over $\;\Bbb F_1\;$:

$$\text{Our polynomial's a root in the field}\;\;\Bbb F_2:=\Bbb F_1[x]/\langle q_1(x)\rangle\;,\;\;\text{namely}\;\;\beta:=\overline x:=x+\langle q_1(x)\rangle$$

Note, again, that $\;[\Bbb F_2:\Bbb F_1]=n-1\implies [\Bbb F_2:\Bbb F]=n(n-1)\;$
And etc.

Note that after the first step, if $\;q_1(x)\;$ happens to be *reducible* over $\;\Bbb F_1\;$ then, taking one of its irreducible factors, we get an extension of degree **less** than $\;n(n-1)\;$ (Fill in details)

Answer (score 1):

If $\alpha$ is a root of $f$ which is not in $F,$ then $[F(\alpha): F] = n.$ For any other root $\beta,$ its minimal polynomial over $F[\alpha]$ has degree at most $n-1$. Applying induction properly should yield an upper bound for your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You might remember the following

**Lemma.** Let $f(X) \in F[X]$ ($F$ here is a field) a polynomial of degree $n \ge 1$. Then there exists a finite field extension $E$ of $F$ in which $f(X)$ has a root. Moreover it is $[E:F] \le n$.

and then conclude using induction on $n$.